# What is this staff skin?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In the Mad King's Labyrinth, what staff skin does this NPC have equipped?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The staff is called [The Crossing](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/The_Crossing).

Comment: And it makes the nougats actually worth collecting. Why nougats don't give a mini, I have no idea.

Comment: @Koviko I'm on a never ending quest to get an Aetherized hammer skin for 400g from the TP, so I've been selling my nougats when I hit 250. Think u can get 1 gold for em.